# Price Line at low and high of latest candle/previous candle

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I am extremely new to Pine Script and I am trying to make a seemingly simple script but failing to do so.

All I want is

i) Draw a horizontal price line (and show the price to the right) at the high of the latest candle.

ii) Draw a horizontal price line (and show the price to the right) at the low of the latest candle or latest but one candle (whichever is the lowest).

Can anyone help me with this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
//@version=3

study("My Script")

//Q1

highline = hline(high[1])

plot(highline, "High Line", color=red, linewidth=2)

//Q2

lowline = hline(low[1])

plot(lowline, "Low Line", color=blue, linewidth=2)
```